# Django file upload as different user

Tags: python, django, apache, docker, mod-wsgi

I have a Django application running on an mod_wsgi (embedded mode) Apache instance inside a Docker container. This container shares a volume (`media/`) with the host.

When a user uploads a file, it is stored in the `media/<file>` directory. The issue is that the file owner and group are both `root`, and I need write access to these for a particular user (`tech`) and/or group (`tech-group`).

I'm assuming it is happening because python is running as `root` in the container(?). Is there a way to instead have it run as `tech`? Or somehow tell Django to write files as a particular user/group?

Comment: Who owns the `media` folder?

Comment: @ruohola It is owned by `tech`/`tech-group`.